# Titan - Weapons of Light perk

Tags: destiny

The Titan has a Weapons of Light perk that they can choose for their bubble shield. It gives a short damage boost to all player who pass through the shield.

- What is the value of the bonus?
- What is the value of the higher performance perk, which enhances Weapon of Light further?
- How long does the perk last?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **What is the value of the bonus?**

The Weapons of Light buff gives you a 25 % damage increase to you and all your allies.

> **What is the value of the higher performance perk, which enhances Weapon of Light further?**

With the Illuminated perk, the buff will give you a 35 % damage increase to you and all your allies.

> **How long does the perk last?**

The Weapons of Light perk lasts 10 seconds.

---

[Source](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Weapons_of_Light)